Unable to start debugging program path is missing or invalid, even though the program is compiled, runs perfectly and has the correct path
enter image description here
I have all the necessary libraries installed on windows to run C program, and the program runs perfectly. But I am not able to debug the code due to this error. Also, yes, the program is compiled and in .exe format in correct path.
I wanted to debug the code, so I ran "c/c++ debug file" in vs code and the build is successful, but this error stops the whole proccess.

Please do not post photos of text. The content of that dialog bos is very simple to describe. Also, if you really need to show content of something on the screen, please do not take a photo but make a screenshot. In Windows you can use Win+Shift+s to cut content of the screen.

Can you show how you compile and run your program? Best is to copy&paste the command line together with the output of the build command into the question. In which path is the binary stored? Can you find the exact path and file in Expolorer?

I use the code runner extension to compile my c programs to .exe files.

When you do this, you should see some output in one of VSCode's windows. Please post this output.

The launch.json is used by the debugger, the code runner has a separate config. Perhaps the settings do not match?

Yep, I think code runner was the problem, I compiled the file manually and tried debugging and its successful. IDK how to get the debugger to work with code runner, but anyways thanks!
